# Has Captain America ever been an ape/monkey?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Hear me out.

I'm asking this because I am looking for some strange comic book stories, but also because in the *Captain America* films, the captain himself draws/has a drawing of a dancing monkey. Yes, I know that it is simultaneously a reference to Captain America's cartoonist roots while also being an allegory for the US government's treatment of Captain America. However, I would just like to know if the captain of America has ever been a simian. The closest thing I can think of is the Marvel Apes universe. I'm guessing that there could be at least one more instance (the '60s were a weird time for comics).

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Rogers_(Earth-8101)

Comment: @JohnP That seems like a proper answer, worthy of more than just being a comment.

Comment: @JAB - Done, although I had posted that before I saw he addressed it in his question. Haven't found any other instances though.

Comment: Technically, he's always been an ape, as humans are apes

Comment: http://thefifthbranch.com/images/oldies/wonderw/ww170/splash.jpg

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9d/08/07/9d08073fc7d8fbf6fc36b45d81b115e0.jpg

Comment: If you're looking for specific "strange comic book stories" (rather than performing an open ended search), you might want to post a [tag:story-identification] question. @Valorum Wrong universe.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Hence why a comment rather than an answer :-)

Comment: I don't recall this scene of Cap drawing himself as a dancing monkey.

Answer (score 11):

If you count the Marvel Apes universe as an example, then yes, Captain America has been depicted as a simian:

[Marvel Apes Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Rogers_(Earth-8101))

[image]

Comment: Note: I'm still digging around, but this is the only reference I can find so far.